# Given a set-to-set function $G$, find a measurable function $f$ that has preimage $f^{-1}=G$

Tags: measure-theory

Consider measurable spaces $(X,\mathcal{X})$, $(Y,\mathcal{Y})$. For any mapping $$G:\mathcal{Y} \to \mathcal{X}$$, can you always find a measurable function $f:X \to Y$ such that $$f^{-1}(B)=G(B)$$, for all $B \in \mathcal{Y}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. For instance, in the special case where both spaces are $\Bbb R$ with Borel's $\sigma$-algebra $\mathscr B$, that would imply the map $$\Phi:\{\text{Borel functions}\}\to \mathscr B^{\mathscr B}\\ f\mapsto f^{-1}[\bullet]$$

is surjective. But this cannot be the case since $\lvert\{\text{Borel functions}\}\rvert=\beth_1$ and $\left\lvert \mathscr B^{\mathscr B}\right\rvert=\beth_1^{\beth_1}=\beth_2$.

Comment: Right! Thank you!